# Does windows server 2012 support enterprise library 2.0

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, windows-server-2012

> Hi
>   Can anyone please advise if server 2012 supports enterprise library 2.0, If yes   how?
>   We can install dot net framework 2.0 by installing 3.5 servicepack in server   2012.Does this also enable installation enterprise library 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes server 2012 supports enterprise library 2.0.

Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 is a full cumulative update that contains many new features building incrementally upon .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and includes cumulative servicing updates to the .NET Framework 2.0 and .NET Framework 3.0 subcomponents.